# Mail sent fine at local and dangerous message while sent in server

Tags: c#, email, httpwebrequest, postman, gmail-api

I have created an app in Gmail console a few months ago.
before some days dangerous message seems in an email
when I send mail using local machine or server it shows dangerous content in mail.
I used local and server same client-id, client secret, access token.

Image URL
https://ibb.co/nR6brFG

Comment: Assuming you're sending this through a custom domain, it seems likely you're missing SPF/DKIM records on your domain. That or the e-mail just seems like a phishing e-mail to Google's system. I don't think this is really a programming problem either way.

Comment: The mail contains SPF/DKIM  details

Comment: This url will be useful. Follow steps and try to find the root cause. https://blog.healthchecks.io/2018/10/investigating-gmails-this-message-seems-dangerous/

Comment: Other things to check: is the (sending) mail server you're using on any blacklist? If you vary the contents of the e-mail (make it more like a normal e-mail) does the same thing happen?

Comment: Upload an image or post the plain text email received at Gmail, maybe we can help you.